# Nodejs ecmascript 6 starter example

Tags: node.js

Looking for a very basic node.js example. With just ecmascript 6 on it. Found babel, but different versions are very confusing.

Also, It will be great, If node-inspector or anything similar points to non-transpiled code.

Comment: here are some links, https://www.lookami.com/using-es6-es2015-in-a-node-js-express/, https://github.com/JustinDrake/node-es6-examples